# Keeping track of a file transfer percentage

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I've begun learning TCP Networking with C#. I've followed the various tutorials and looked at the example code out there and have a working TCP server and client via async connections and writes/reads. I've got file transfers working as well.

Now I'd like to be able to track the progress of the transfer (0% -> 100%) on both the server and the client. When initiating the transfer from the server to client I send the expected file size, so the client knows how many bytes to expect, so I imagine I can easily do: *curCount / totalCount* on the client. But I'm a bit confused about how to do this for the server.

How accurate can the server tell the transfer situation for the client? Should I guess based on the server's own status (either via the networkStream.BeginWrite() callback, or via the chunk loading from disk and networking writing)? Or should I have the client relay back to the server the client's completion?

I'd like to know this for when to close the connection, as well as be able to visually display progress. Should the server trust the client to close the connection (barring network errors/timeouts/etc)? Or can the server close the connection as soon as it's written to the stream?

Comment: The server can safely close the connection as soon as it's done writing all of the bytes to the stream. You're never going to know exactly what the client's status is from the server side without adversely affecting the file transfer, but you can track the percentage sent.

Comment: Ok, I figured that's probably the way it'd be. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two distinct percentages of completion here: the client's and the server's. If you consider the server to be done when it has sent the last byte, the server's percentage will always be at least as high as the client's. If you consider the server to be done when the client has processed the last byte the server's percentage will lag the one of the client. No matter what you do you will have differing values on both ends.

The values will differ by the amount of data currently queued in the various buffers between the server app and the client app. This buffer space is usually quite small. AFAIK the maximum TCP window size is by default 200ms of data transfer.

Probably, you don't need to worry about this issue at all because the progress values of both parties will be tightly tied to each other.

> Should I guess based on the server's own status (either via the networkStream.BeginWrite() callback, or via the chunk loading from disk and networking writing)?

This is an adequate solution.

> Or should I have the client relay back to the server the client's completion?

This would be the 2nd case I described in my 1st paragraph. Also acceptable, although not necessarily a better result and more overhead. I cannot imagine a situation right now in which I'd do it this way.

> Should the server trust the client to close the connection (barring network errors/timeouts/etc)?

When one party of a TCP exchange is done sending it should shutdown the socket for sending (using `Socket.Shutdown(Send)`). This will cause the other party to read zero bytes and know that the transfer is done.

Before closing a socket, it should be shut down. If the `Shutdown` call completes without error it is guaranteed that the remote party has received all data and that the local party has received all data as well.

> Or can the server close the connection as soon as it's written to the stream?

First, shut down, then close. Closing alone does not imply successful transfer.

Comment: Ok. And what about if I want to send 2 or more files, in serial? Should I use the same stream, with demarkation between files? Or should I shutdown and close the existing before creating a new stream?

Comment: Reusing the same connection saves some overhead per file that you transfer. If you transfer few large files it does not matter which one you pick. So chose what is more convenient to you. If you transfer 1m 1 byte files you should indeed reuse the connection.

Comment: @user42524 Instead of demarkation between files, I'd send some metadata (number of files, size of each file) before the first file to aid the client in tracking percentage complete of each file.